# foreach command in tcl to read a file

Tags: loops, foreach, tcl

I have 6 files in a directory; `A.v`, `A.def`, `B.v`, `B.def`, `C.v`, `C.def`.

I want to read the `A.v` and `A.def` files at once and go to `B.v` and `B.def` and so on. I am using the following snippet to carry out the above-said function but it is throwing errors.

```
foreach i [glob "./*.v"] {
    read_verilog $i.v
    read_def $i.def
}
```

I would like to set the variable to read just the name A, B, C etc.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`file rootname`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M32) command here:

```
foreach file [glob -nocomplain "./*.v"] {
    read_verilog $file
    read_def [file rootname $file].def
}
```